# EF Core нет связи many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Связь решил сделать с `ICollection`. У меня следующие классы. Как допустим вывести все Recipient для определенной группы? Пытаюсь делать вот так, но `ThenInclude` он не дает получить `Recipient`.

```
{
    var group = db.Groups.Include(x => x.GroupRecipients).ThenInclude(y=>y.)

                .FirstOrDefault(gr => gr.Id == id);                       
}

public class Recipient
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Number { get;set; }
public ICollection<grouprecipient> GroupRecipients { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public ICollection<grouprecipient> GroupRecipients { get; set; }
}

public class GroupRecipient
{
public int GroupId { get; set; }
public Group Group { get; set; }

public int RecipientId { get; set; }
public Recipient Recipient { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupRecipient>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.GroupId, t.RecipientId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupRecipient>()
            .HasOne(sc => sc.Group)
            .WithMany(s => s.GroupRecipients)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.GroupId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupRecipient>()
            .HasOne(sc => sc.Recipient)
            .WithMany(c => c.GroupRecipients)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.RecipientId);

    }
}
```

Метод в контроллере

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Group Get(int id)
{
    var group = db.Groups
        .Include(x => x.GroupRecipients)
        .ThenInclude(gr => gr.Recipient)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);                       
    return group;
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему вы пробовали добавить через intellisense, но вроде в 2017 VS есть баг на это дело. Попробуйте добавить вручную `.ThenInclude(y=>y.Recipient)`.

Comment: Заголовок я не совсем понимаю. Поправте если необходимо.

Comment: Вы забыли указать DbSet для GroupRecipient

Comment: @null да, тоже не раз встречал этот баг и непонимал в чём дело, значит не только у меня )). Решалось просто написание названия вручную в обход intellisense.

Comment: C  этим  .ThenInclude(y=>y.Recipient)  разобрался.Дело действительно было в intellisense. Но почему то api запрос (api/groups/1)  выдает следующий json {"id":1,"name":"NewTestGroup","description":"Тестовое Описание","groupRecipients":[{"groupId":1 То есть неполный ответ. Запрос:        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Group Get(int id)
        {
            var group = db.Groups
                .Include(x => x.GroupRecipients)
                .ThenInclude(gr => gr.Recipient)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);                       
            return group;
        }

Comment: Разобрался.Дело вот в этом                services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                    Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });

Answer (score 1):

Дело вот в этом:

```
  services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```